# How to display S3 files for each user using PHP foreach

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-s3

I am using Amazon S3 to store photos uploaded by users, using the following code:

```
        if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){

        $fileName = $_FILES['theFile']['name'];
        $fileTempName = $_FILES['theFile']['tmp_name'];
        $folderName = "{id}/{address}/$fileName";

        //create a new bucket
        $s3->putBucket("bucket_name", S3::ACL_PUBLIC_READ);

        //move the file
        if ($s3->putObjectFile($fileTempName, "bucket_name", $folderName, S3::ACL_PUBLIC_READ)) {
            echo ""; //etc, etc
```

The `{id}` and `{address}` are dynamic variables used to create the appearance of folders when the files are uploaded, based on each user's unique data stored in a mysql database.

The problem I'm having is displaying these files inside each user's password protected site. The code I'm using below pics up ALL user's photos and displays them to ALL users. If `{id}/{address}/$fileName` converts to `123/figuero/photo.jpg` then user `123` should only be able to see `123/figuero/photo.jpg` (or any other files with the preface `123/` or `123/xxx/`

With the code I'm using below, ALL files inside `bucket_name` can be seen by ALL users, instead of just the files associated with the dynamic data associated with their photos:

```
    <ul>
        <?php
            $i = 0;
            $contents = $s3->getBucket("bucket_name");

             foreach($contents as $file)
             {

             $fname = $file['name'];
             $furl = 'http://bucket_name.s3.amazonaws.com/'.$fname;

                 echo "<li><img src='$furl'></li>";
                 {
                     $i = 0; 
                 }
             }
        ?>
    <ul>
```

In other words, *ALL* the files inside http://bucket_name.S3.amazonaws.com/ are being pulled up for display by the code, instead of just the photos pertaining to user `123` inside the files prefaced by `123/xxx/`

What am I missing? Thanks much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to use some sort of prefix on the bucket name for your "directory" type needs.  Other than that, you'll need to evaluate the directory name in the file name before echoing.

[List all Files in a S3 Directory with Zend Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8030837/list-all-files-in-a-s3-directory-with-zend-framework)

i.e. using bucket name to differentiate:

```
if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){

$fileName = $_FILES['theFile']['name'];
$fileTempName = $_FILES['theFile']['tmp_name'];
$folderName = "{id}/{address}/$fileName";
$bucketName = "bucket_name" . $folderName;

//create a new bucket
$s3->putBucket($bucketName, S3::ACL_PUBLIC_READ);

//move the file
if ($s3->putObjectFile($fileTempName, $bucketName, $folderName, S3::ACL_PUBLIC_READ)) {
    echo ""; //etc, etc
```

and

```
<ul>
    <?php
        $i = 0;
        $contents = $s3->getBucket($bucketName);

         foreach($contents as $file)
         {

         $fname = $file['name'];
         $furl = 'http://bucket_name.s3.amazonaws.com/'.$fname;

             echo "<li><img src='$furl'></li>";
             {
                 $i = 0; 
             }
         }
    ?>
<ul>
```

Comment: Hmmmm, this creates a bucket by the name `bucket_name{id}.s3.amazonaws.com/{id}/{address}` instead of `bucket_name.s3.amazonaws.com/{id}/{address}`

Comment: Sure... you could name the bucket anything you want really.  The idea is that you can get that specific bucket using the S3 api call as opposed to iterating through all files in a bucket and evaluating within the loop.

Comment: It's not the bucket name I'm having a problem with. The dynamic variable `{id}` is getting placed after `bucket_name` and creating a bucket name called `bucket_name{id}` instead of `bucket_name`

Comment: yes, that is the idea.  You could make it bucket_name_id or bucket_name_id_address or bucket_name_<insert whatever you'd like here>.  You're needing to do this so that you can use this name when you need to retrieve the bucket.

Comment: That would create hundreds, eventually thousands of buckets (because there are hundreds of members), since {id} identifies a specific member folder to place their photos in. I want to create one bucket for all member folders, which are identified by their member id `{id}`

Comment: Thanks Benjamin. But the original question explains how I'm trying to create folders in ONE BUCKET. Folders are identified by member IDs, created on uploading a photo, resulting in `http://bucket_name.s3.amazonaws.com/123/figuero/photo.jpg`. In this example, the folder `/123/` is the result of picking up the member's ID, using the dynamic variable `{id}`

Comment: I understand your conundrum, but there are only so many things that you can do with S3.  The alternative is to iterate through the bucket and evaluate the id as you are looping (which I also included in the original answer).  Hope that helps.

Comment: Maybe you could list the objects instead?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4932892/amazon-s3-folders-problem

Comment: The problem is not creating a bucket or even the folders with the existing code in my original question. It works just fine. The problem is in the DISPLAY (which is in the foreach argument). Because Amazon doesn't recognize folders, everything after `.amazonaws.com/` is seen as a file. That's why ALL USERS see ALL PHOTOS from the above code in the foreach command. I need something that's going to allow ONLY User 123 to see ONLY photos (ie files) beginning with `123/xxx`

Comment: It seems as though you have something in your head that you can't see past, so unfortunately the answers available to you are not the one's that you will accept.  You either need to reduce the initial set (by using more buckets), or evaluate the name of the file to determine if the user's id that you're looking for is in the filepath (keep your loop, but add an if statement).  Good luck to you.